# $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ as a Fréchet space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I think I'm misunderstanding what is being asked of me in the following question:

> The  space  $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ has a Fréchet space topology with respect  to  which $f_n \rightarrow f$ iff $f^{(k)}_n \rightarrow f^{(k)}$ uniformly on all compact subsets ($k$, non-negative, is the order of derivative).

To show the backwards implication I need to show that convergence ($f^{(k)}_n \rightarrow f^{(k)}$ uniformly on all compact subsets) give me seminorms, there are countably many such semi norms, and these seminorms give me a complete Hausdorff TVS. My book gives me some facts to help me in this direction.

I'm confused by the forward implication though - if endow the space of  $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with a topology given by countable seminorms which makes $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ a complete Hausdorff TVS -- how do I know this implies $f^{(k)}_n \rightarrow f^{(k)}$ uniformly on all compact subsets? What if the seminorms are really strange and have nothing to do with the derivatives of $f$ over compact subsets?

Comment: The seminirms are $p_{n,k}(f):= \sup_{[-k,k]} |f^{(n)}|$. The key is that any compact set is contained in some interval $[-k,k]$

Comment: I see that, but that's for a particular choice of seminorms. Why should it be true for any arbitrary countable family of seminorms though?

Comment: For fixed k,n,m, The set ${p_{n,k}(f,0)<m}$ is open, so for your Family of seminorms, you can put a p- Bail inside.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this statement, what is a p-ball and why is it suffient for one p-ball to be inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question doesn't exclude that there are different topologies on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is a Frechet space with this topology. However, since the open mapping theorem is also true for Frechet spaces, we cannot have a finer (or weaker) topology (as the usual one) on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ in which $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is also a Frechet space and $f^{(k)}_n \rightarrow f^{(k)}$ uniformly on compact sets for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

One can proof that $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$ in the sense of Hamel basis. Thus you can take e.g. the Banach-space $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and transport the norm to $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. With these norm $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$  is a Banach space. Since the topology of local convergence of all derivates is not normable, this weird topology is different than the usual one.

Comment: why does "no finer topology" follow from the open mapping theorem?

Comment: If $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$ are topologies on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$, i.e. $\tau_2$ is finer than $\tau_1$, then $\mathrm{id} \colon (C^\infty(\mathbb{R}),\tau_2) \rightarrow  (C^\infty(\mathbb{R}),\tau_1)$ the map is continuous. If both topologies are Frechet, then the open mapping theorem already implies that this map is open, i.e. the inverse map $\mathrm{id} \colon (C^\infty(\mathbb{R}),\tau_1) \rightarrow  (C^\infty(\mathbb{R}),\tau_2)$ is continuous and thus $\tau_1 = \tau_2$.

Comment: I like this, but my only problem is that we haven't covered the open mapping theorem for Frechet spaces. Is there a way to adapt Tito Aliatron's hints into this? I'm looking through the proof of the open mapping theorem for Frechet spaces to see if I can do it too.

Comment: I don't think that you can prove this much easier. It is a feature coming from the completeness of the space. You may have a look in Rudin's book on functional analysis. There you can find a proof of the open mapping theorem - that is Theorem 2.11. In fact, the idea of the proof is the same as in the case of banach spaces.